# In Javascript, When removing the middle item from an array, why isn't the time complexity O(n/2)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, big-o

To my understanding, when we say "remove" an item from an array, we say that the time complexity of performing such an operation is O(n) because we have to account for the worst-case scenario. However, when removing the middle item from an array, we know for certain that we'll have to change/iterate the index of just half the items in the array, however the time complexity is still O(n) instead of O(n/2) why?

I guess there is a good reason for it.

Comment: If it is an array, I assume it's a contiguous block of addresses. You would still need to shift each of the remaining items—to the right—to the left by one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the proper forum for this question. You should post this question in "Computer Science" on the StackExchange

Comment: Link for the lazy: https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm sorry I quite don't understand what you are trying to say, I get that if we just ask for the time complexity of "removing" an item, we assume the worst case, but if we are asked specifically for the time complexity of  removing the "middle item" we just have to shift half of the items every single time, and yet the answer to the question is O(n) instead of O(n/2)

Comment: n/2 = (1/2)n, but O notation ignores constant factors in front of n, so the 1/2 is simply dropped. It is important to understand that O notation *doesn't* indicate the precise number of steps in an algorithm. Instead, it indicates the asymptotic complexity of an algorithm.

Comment: TLDR: O(n) == O(n/2)